# Input step with Boolean parameter is always true in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I added an input step to my Jenkins pipeline with a Boolean parameter. However no matter if I check or uncheck the box when running the pipeline, the console output always shows "YEAH".

What am I missing here? My understanding is that if the user unchecks the parameter, then the script should enter the else-statement.

```
stage('Dockerize') {                
    input {
        message 'Build Docker image'
        parameters {
            booleanParam(name: 'BUILD_DOCKER_IMAGE', defaultValue: true, description: 'Uncheck to skip creation of Docker image.')
        }
    }
    steps {
        script {
            if (BUILD_DOCKER_IMAGE) {
                echo "YEAH"
            } else {
                echo "NAY"
            }
        }                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of the statements `PARAMETERNAME` and `env.PARAMETERNAME` is always `String`, regardless of actual parameter type. This is because they are passed around as environment variables, which can be only strings.

To preserve the original type use `params.PARAMETERNAME`:

```groovy
if (params.BUILD_DOCKER_IMAGE) {
  // Do stuff here...
}
```

Cleaner and more type-safe than `BUILD_DOCKER_IMAGE.toBoolean()`.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that I need to parse the variable as a Boolean:

```
if (BUILD_DOCKER_IMAGE.toBoolean()) {
  // Do stuff here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

they are both correct, but rather than using Parms, you should probably create a proper variable if you intend to do all the docker work in the same stage, other wise create an env var.

You should have a condition first and echo a statement telling the team that it is disabled for this reason..... blah.blah and should you  build the image grab the input, evaluate them and build a command based on you imputs ... Then run it.

```
        if (env.usePlistFile.toBoolean()) {
            sh """
                echo "---------------------------------------------------" 
                echo "Do  Wrapping With pList"
                echo "---------------------------------------------------"
                echo "IntuneMAMPackager -f settings.plist"
            """
        } else {
                def wrapOpts= input(
                    id: 'signIn', message: 'What are the credentials for the Apple Store Login ?',
                    parameters: [
                        string(
                            defaultValue: '',
                            description: 'Path to the input native iOS application or previously packaged iOS application ?',
                            name: 'i'
                        ),
                        string(
                            defaultValue: 'wrappedApp.ipa',
                            description: 'What is the output file name ?',
                            name: 'o'
                        ),
                        string(
                            defaultValue: 'provision.mobileprovision', 
                            description: 'What is mobile provision file ?', 
                            name: 'p'
                        ),
                        string(
                            defaultValue: 'provision.mobileprovision', 
                            description: 'Name or SHA1 hash of the certificate ?', 
                            name: 'c'
                        ),
                        string(
                            defaultValue: 'provision.mobileprovision', 
                            description: '(Optional) Authority URI of the input app if the app uses the Microsoft Authentication Library ?', 
                            name: 'aa'
                        ),
                        string(
                            defaultValue: 'provision.mobileprovision', 
                            description: '(Optional) Client ID of the input app if the app uses the Microsoft Authentication Library ?', 
                            name: 'ac'
                        ),
                        string(
                            defaultValue: 'provision.mobileprovision', 
                            description: '(Optional) Reply URI of the input app if the app uses the Microsoft Authentication Library ?', 
                            name: 'ar'
                        ),
                        string(
                            defaultValue: '',
                            description: '(Optional) Prevent default build string update. If a value is supplied, it will be used as the new build string ?',
                            name: 'b'
                        ),
                        booleanParam(
                            defaultValue: 'false',
                            description: '(Optional) Remove missing entitlements during packaging ?',
                            name: 'e'
                        ),
                        booleanParam(
                            defaultValue: 'false',
                            description: '(Optional) Prints information about the iOS extensions in the app, and what entitlements are required to use them ?',
                            name: 'xe'
                        ),
                        string(
                            defaultValue: '',
                            description: '(Optional) An array of paths to extension provisioning profiles ?',
                            name: 'x'
                        ),
                        booleanParam(
                            defaultValue: 'false',
                            description: '(Optional) Output verbose messages to the console ?',
                            name: 'v'
                        ),
                        string(
                            defaultValue: 'settings.plist',
                            description: '(Optional) Path to a plist file specifying arguments ?',
                            name: 'f'
                        ),
                        booleanParam(
                            defaultValue: 'false',
                            description: '(Optional) Disable collection of Microsoft Intune client telemetry ?',
                            name: 'dt'
                        ), 
                        booleanParam(
                            defaultValue: 'false',
                            description: '(Optional) Disable MSAL log override ?',
                            name: 'dl'
                        ),
                    ])
                def opt_i = wrapOpts.i?:''
                def opt_o = wrapOpts.o?:''
                def opt_p = wrapOpts.p?:''
                def opt_c = wrapOpts.c?:''
                def opt_aa = wrapOpts.aa?:''
                def opt_ac = wrapOpts.ac?:''
                def opt_ar = wrapOpts.ar?:''
                def opt_b = wrapOpts.b?:''
                def opt_e = wrapOpts.e?:false
                def opt_xe = wrapOpts.xe?:false
                def opt_x = wrapOpts.x?:''
                def opt_v = wrapOpts.v?:false
                def opt_f = wrapOpts.f?:''
                def opt_dt = wrapOpts.dt?:false
                def opt_dl = wrapOpts.dl?:false

                echo "Option (i): ${opt_i}"
                echo "Option (o): ${opt_o}"
                echo "Option (p): ${opt_p}"
                echo "Option (c): ${opt_c}"
                echo "Option (aa): ${opt_aa}"
                echo "Option (ac): ${opt_ac}"
                echo "Option (ar): ${opt_ar}"
                echo "Option (b): ${opt_b}"
                echo "Option (e): ${opt_e}"
                echo "Option (xe): ${opt_xe}"
                echo "Option (x): ${opt_x}"
                echo "Option (v): ${opt_v}"
                echo "Option (f): ${opt_f}"
                echo "Option (dt): ${opt_dt}"
                echo "Option (dl): ${opt_dl}"

                def cmd_line = "IntuneMAMPackager " 
                if ( opt_i != null || opt_i != "" ) { cmd_line  += " -i ${opt_i} " }
                if ( opt_o != null || opt_i != "" ) { cmd_line  += " -o ${opt_o} " }
                if ( opt_p != null || opt_i != "" ) { cmd_line  += " -p ${opt_p} " }
                if ( opt_c != null || opt_i != "" ) { cmd_line  += " -c ${opt_c} " }
                if ( opt_aa != null || opt_i != "" ) { cmd_line  += " -aa ${opt_aa} " }
                if ( opt_ac != null || opt_i != "" ) { cmd_line  += " ac ${opt_ac} " }
                if ( opt_ar != null || opt_i != "" ) { cmd_line  += " -ar ${opt_ar} " }
                if ( opt_b != null || opt_i != "" ) { cmd_line  += " -b ${opt_b} " }
                if ( opt_e.toBoolean() = true ) { cmd_line  += " -e " }
                if (opt_xe.toBoolean()  = true ) { cmd_line  += " -xe " }
                if (opt_x != null || ${opt_i} != "" ) { cmd_line  += " -x ${opt_x} " }
                if (opt_v.toBoolean() = true ) { cmd_line  += " -v " }
                if (opt_f != null || ${opt_i} != "" ) { cmd_line  += " -f ${opt_f} " }
                if (opt_dt.toBoolean()  = true ) { cmd_line  += " -dt " }
                if (opt_dl.toBoolean()  = true ) { cmd_line  += " -dl " }
            sh """
                echo "---------------------------------------------------" 
                echo "Do  Wrapping"
                echo "---------------------------------------------------"

                ${cmd_line}
            """ 
        }
    }
```